# MassTransit messages not picked up

Tags: msmq, masstransit

I'm using MassTransit version 2.7.0 to communicate between a web service and a web site. The web service publishes messages and the website subscribes to them.

Publisher service:

```
    ServiceBus = ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
        {
            sbc.UseMsmq();
            sbc.VerifyMsmqConfiguration();
            sbc.ReceiveFrom("msmq://localhost/publisher");
            sbc.UseMulticastSubscriptionClient();
        });
```

Subscriber website:

```
    ServiceBus = ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
        {
            sbc.UseMsmq();
            sbc.VerifyMsmqConfiguration();
            sbc.ReceiveFrom("msmq://localhost/website");
            sbc.UseMulticastSubscriptionClient();

            sbc.Subscribe(s =>
                {
                    s.Handler<SomethingHappened>(HandleSomethingHappened);
                });
        });
```

Everything works fine on my dev machine but not on the live site. The messages are showing up in the website_subscriptions MSMQ queue, but they aren't getting picked up by the subscribed website. The server does have multiple NICs so I added [the registry settings to support that](http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/troubleshooting/index.html). I don't get any errors or anything - it just doesn't pickup the messages from the queue.

Am I missing some configuration or permissions problem? Is there some way to see why it isn't working?

**[edit]**
I just noticed that the website_subscriptions queue is all messages from the framework: AddPeerMessage and AddPeerSubscriptionMessage. All the messages from the service (SomethingHappened in the above example) are in the error queue.

Comment: You might try setting up the [Log4Net](http://nuget.org/packages/MassTransit.Log4Net) or [NLog](http://nuget.org/packages/MassTransit.NLog) integration to see what is happening in MassTransit. They did a great job of logging lots of useful troubleshooting information.

Comment: @Clay, I was able to get logging set up and now I see it's an exception thrown by the subscriber. If you make an answer repeating what your comment says, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try setting up the Log4Net or NLog integration to see what is happening in MassTransit. They did a great job of logging lots of useful troubleshooting information.